# RFC3414 - How is SNMP need not protect against DDOS or Traffic Analysis Attack?

Tags: snmp, rfc

I've been reading RFC3414 about User-based Security Model (USM) for version 3 of the Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMPv3) , and it says :

> There are at least two threats that an SNMP Security Model need not
>      protect against.  The security protocols defined in this memo do not
>      provide protection against:
>
> - Denial of Service This SNMP Security Model does not attempt to
>       address the broad range of attacks by which service on behalf of
>       authorized users is denied.  Indeed, such denial-of-service attacks
>       are in many cases indistinguishable from the type of network
>       failures with which any viable network management protocol must
>       cope as a matter of course.
> - Traffic Analysis This SNMP Security Model does not attempt to
>      address traffic analysis attacks.  Indeed, many traffic patterns
>      are predictable - devices may be managed on a regular basis by a
>      relatively small number of management applications - and therefore
>      there is no significant advantage afforded by protecting against
>      traffic analysis.

I didn't quite understand how SNMP need not protect against them. Can someone explain this clearly please ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Except a few vendors who published their test SNMP agent on the internet, most devices are in private networks, and the risks of such threats are relatively low and manageable.

Comment: But why ? I don't understand that part. How is it manageable when it's in private networks?

Comment: Because in a corporate network you have your own network devices where you can enforce security and log the messages. Too broad to cover the details and you need to consult a security specialist.